# Total Present Value of Multiple Cash Flows

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I understand how to calculate the total accumulated and present values of multiple cash flows over *n* years, but I don't quite understand how this works when *m* of those *n* years aren't included.

For example, say I have the following cash flows:

- $50 due in 1 year from today
- $100 due in 2 years from today
- $200 due yearly at 3, 4, 5, ..., 20 years from today

How would I go about calculating the total present value today of these cash flows with an interest rate of 8% per annum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the time value of money, due to the constant interest rate, your cash flow stream is equivalent to $50$ for $20$ years, $50$ from years $2$ through $20$, and $100$ from years $3$ through $20$. (Draw a timeline of both scenarios to convince yourself that this is true.)

The $50$ for $20$ years has present value $$50\left(\dfrac{1-(1/1.08)^{20}}{0.08}\right) = 50a_{\overline{20}|8\%}$$
(I hope you know this formula if you're doing a finance class!). The $50$ from years $2$ through $20$ consists of $19$ payments, with present value $$50\left(\dfrac{1-(1/1.08)^{19}}{0.08}\right) = 50a_{\overline{19}|8\%}$$
*but* this values the annuity at year $1$ and not at the present time, so we need to bring this back one year by multiplying by $\dfrac{1}{1.08}$:
$$\dfrac{50}{1.08}\left(\dfrac{1-(1/1.08)^{19}}{0.08}\right) = 50a_{\overline{19}|8\%}v_{8\%}\text{.}$$
The $100$ from years $3$ through $20$ has present value (using a similar method as above):
$$\dfrac{100}{1.08^2}\left(\dfrac{1-(1/1.08)^{18}}{0.08}\right) = 100a_{\overline{18}|8\%}v^2_{8\%}\text{.}$$
Hence, the present value is 
$$50a_{\overline{20}|8\%} + 50a_{\overline{19}|8\%}v_{8\%} +  100a_{\overline{18}|8\%}v^2_{8\%}\text{.}$$

Answer (score 1):

You just discount the first two and add them up. The last you can either do the same way-a spreadsheet makes it easy-or you can recognize that you have a geometric series.  The value of the cash flow is $200(1+0.08)^{-3}+200(1+0.08)^{-4}+\dots 200(1+0.08)^{-20}$ and sum the finite geometric series.  The ratio is $1/1.08$ and the starting term is ????

Comment: You haven't defined $a_n$ and your comment seems far removed from your question.  Your comment seems to be asking how to discount one payment to present value, while the question asked about the case where some payments are different. If you can't discount one payment, you won't understand how to discount multiple payments.  I corrected the answer because standard discounting is dividing by $1+i$,not multiplying by $1-i$.  If $i$ times the term is small compared to $1$, they are very close.

Comment: $a_{\overline{n}|}$ is standard actuarial notation. For an interest rate $i \neq 0, -1$, define the discount factor $v = \dfrac{1}{1+i}$. Then $$a_{\overline{n}|} = v + v^2 + \cdots + v^n = \dfrac{1-v^n}{i}\text{.}$$